# Term for the relation between points A and B of a directed graph such that there exists at least one vertex accessible from A but not from B?

Tags: graph-theory

I know this is an extremely specific thing to need a name for, and I don't expect that one already exists, but is there a reasonable name that might be applied to the idea?

I would also like a term for the opposite possibility, for the relation holding between vertices A and B such that there is at least one vertex from which A is reachable but B is not.

Thanks in advance if you can help me find reasonable terms for these concepts.

EDIT: I'm referring here specifically to some vertex *other than A and B themselves*. I failed to make that clear initially.

Comment: If your definition of accessibility implies that $A$ is accessible from $A$, then this is just the same as saying that $A$ is not accessible from $B$.

Comment: I should have mentioned the assumption that said "at least one vertex" is not identical to either! Shall edit - thanks for the correction.